# Custom submission handler doesn't save the node

Tags: 7, forms

I have two form submission buttons: the normal one and one added via `hook_form_alter`.

I'm currently using the normal default one as a save button which updates the node content as normal.

The second one which is called submit does the same thing, but will be changing a checkbox via `$form_state` prior to saving the node content.

The code I'm using is the following one:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'example_node_form') {

    //dpm($form);
    $form['actions']['finishbutton'] = [
      '#type'   => 'submit',
      '#value'  => t('Submit'),
      '#submit' => array_merge($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], ['custom_submit']),
      '#weight' => 99,
    ];
  }
}

function custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  drupal_set_message(t('This works, but shows up after the node submit message'));

  // Shows after the node save message.
  dpm($form_state);

  // Doesn't update.
  $form_state['values']['field_nomination_submitted'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 1;
}
```

My submission works, but the custom handler appears to be firing after the standard submission handler. Do I need to switch the array_merge order? Do I need to break this into separate functions? Do I potentially need to add a submit function inside of custom_submit?

Comment: Given the arguments passed to `array_merge()`, `custom_submit()` is put after the other submission handlers.

Comment: Yes, your function would need to fire first

Comment: Cool, apparently using [] syntax instead of Array() and switching the order works. Thank!.

Comment: Maybe consider buying a PHPStorm license. And then configure it to follow Drupal coding standards. This will probably prevent you lots of headaches in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` syntax instead of `Array()` and switch the order ... that should work.

Credits: [Shawn Matthews](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/34942/shawn-matthews).